# Convert Email to twilio phone number to Text

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to send an email to my `Twilio` phone numbers?

[image]

The “To” would be a `Twilio` phone number?  The “Subject” is a 10 digit phone number where I want a text sent.  The “Body” would be the text.  Can this be done without code in a Twimlet?  Is there an example?

Comment: You are trying to send an email to a phone number?

Comment: "To" can't be a phone number. You can't send an email to a phone number. You can send an email to another email address. 555555555 is not a valid email address. Replace your "YYY@YYYY" with something valid because that's not a valid email address.